# Cinema scheduling

Tags: java, beginner, swing

Even though I have asked a question here related to my app [using Swing and creating `JPanel`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85753/using-swing-and-creating-jpanel), I still have other ones about best practice making applications. I'm using Java 8.

I have this class screening which contains `Film` and `Auditorium` classes. At the moment the class looks like this:

**Screening.java**

```
package cinema.schedule;

import cinema.Auditorium;
import cinema.film.Film;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Screening {
    public final Auditorium auditorium;
    public final Film film;

    private float ticketPrice;
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;

    public Screening(Film film, LocalDateTime startDateTime) {
        this(new Auditorium(), 0, startDateTime, film);
    }

    public Screening(Film film, float ticketPrice, LocalDateTime startDateTime) {
        this(new Auditorium(), ticketPrice, startDateTime, film);
    }

    public Screening(Auditorium auditorium, float ticketPrice, LocalDateTime startDateTime, Film film) {
        this.auditorium = auditorium;
        this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        this.film = film;
    }

    public float getTicketPrice() {
        return ticketPrice;
    }

    public void setTicketPrice(float ticketPrice) {
        this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
    }

    public LocalTime getStartTime() {
        return startDateTime.toLocalTime();
    }

    public void setStartTime(LocalDateTime startDateTime) {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Screening{" +
                "switcher=" + auditorium +
                ", film=" + film +
                ", ticketPrice=" + ticketPrice +
                ", startDateTime=" + startDateTime +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Screening screening = (Screening) o;

        if(Float.compare(screening.ticketPrice, ticketPrice) != 0) return false;
        if(film != null ? !film.equals(screening.film) : screening.film != null) return false;
        if(startDateTime != null ? !startDateTime.equals(screening.startDateTime) : screening.startDateTime != null)
            return false;
        if(auditorium != null ? !auditorium.equals(screening.auditorium) : screening.auditorium != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = auditorium != null ? auditorium.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (film != null ? film.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (ticketPrice != +0.0f ? Float.floatToIntBits(ticketPrice) : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (startDateTime != null ? startDateTime.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Auditorium.java**

```
package cinema;

public class Auditorium {
    private int totalSeats;
    private int occupiedSeats;

    public static Auditorium of(Auditorium auditorium) {
        Auditorium instance = new Auditorium();
        instance.occupiedSeats = auditorium.occupiedSeats;
        instance.totalSeats = auditorium.totalSeats;
        return instance;
    }

    public Auditorium() {
        this(10);
    }

    public Auditorium(int totalSeats) {
        this.totalSeats = totalSeats;
        this.occupiedSeats = 0;
    }

    public void occupySeats(int count) {
        if (getEmptySeats() >= count) {
            occupiedSeats += count;
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Not enough seats");
        }
    }

    public boolean hasEmptySeats() {
        return !(totalSeats <= occupiedSeats);
    }

    public int getEmptySeats() {
        return totalSeats - occupiedSeats;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Auditorium{" +
                "totalSeats=" + totalSeats +
                ", occupiedSeats=" + occupiedSeats +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Film.java**

```
    package cinema.film;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.time.Duration;

    public class Film {
        private String title;
        private Genre genre;
        private String description;
        private Duration duration;
        private String pathToImage;
        private Language language;
        private Subtitles subtitles;
        private RecommendedAge recommendedAge;

        public Film() {}

        public Film(String title, Genre genre, String filmLengthInDecimal, Language language, Subtitles subtitles, RecommendedAge recommendedAge, String description, String imageTitle, String pathToDir) {
            this.title = title;
            this.genre = genre;
            this.description = description;
            setLenghtInHours(filmLengthInDecimal);
            this.pathToImage = pathToDir + imageTitle;
            this.language = language;
            this.subtitles = subtitles;
            this.recommendedAge = recommendedAge;
        }

        public Film(Film film) {
            this.title = film.title;
            this.genre = film.genre;
            this.description = film.description;
            this.duration = film.duration;
            this.pathToImage = film.pathToImage;
            this.language = film.language;
            this.subtitles = film.subtitles;
            this.recommendedAge = film.recommendedAge;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public Genre getGenre() {
            return genre;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getDurationTime() {
            long s = duration.getSeconds();
            return String.format("%d:%02d", s/3600, (s%3600)/60);
        }

        public Duration getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public Language getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public Subtitles getSubtitles() {
            return subtitles;
        }

        public RecommendedAge getRecommendedAge() {
            return recommendedAge;
        }

        public Icon getIcon() {
            return new ImageIcon(pathToImage);
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void setGenre(String genre) {
            this.genre = Genre.valueOf(genre);
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public void setLenghtInHours(String lengthInHours) {
            double timeInDecimal = Double.parseDouble(lengthInHours);
            int fullHours = ((int) timeInDecimal);
            int minutes = (int) ((timeInDecimal - fullHours + 0.001) * 100);
            this.duration = Duration.ofMinutes((fullHours * 60) + minutes);
        }

        public void setPathToImage(String pathToImage) {
            this.pathToImage = pathToImage;
        }

        public void setLanguage(String language) {
            this.language = Language.valueOf(language);
        }

        public void setSubtitles(String subtitles) {
            this.subtitles = Subtitles.valueOf(subtitles);
        }

        public void setRecommendedAge(String recommendedAge) {
            this.recommendedAge = RecommendedAge.valueOf(recommendedAge);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Movie{" +
                    "title='" + title + '\'' +
                    ", genre='" + genre + '\'' +
                    ", length='" + getDurationTime() + '\'' +
                    ", imageTitle='" + pathToImage + '\'' +
                    ", language='" + language + '\'' +
                    ", subtitles='" + subtitles + '\'' +
                    ", recommendedAge='" + getRecommendedAge() + '\'' +
                    ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

    }
```

1. Should I leave it like this or change something about public final instance variables? What are my options?

I'm using it in **FilmsPanel.java**.

```
package gui.panel.film;

import cinema.schedule.Screening;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilmsPanel extends JPanel {
    private final JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();
    private List<JButton> filmButton = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Screening> screeningList;

    public  FilmsPanel(String title) {
        if (title != null) {
            container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Films"));
        }
        add(container);
    }

    public void setScreeningSet(List<Screening> screeningList) {
        this.screeningList = screeningList;
        updateDateButtons();
    }

    public void addFilmListener(FilmsListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(FilmsListener.class, listener);

    }

    public void removeFilmListener(FilmsListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(FilmsListener.class, listener);
    }

    private void updateDateButtons(){
        deleteDateButtons();
        createDateButtons();
    }

    private void deleteDateButtons() {
        filmButton.stream().forEach(container::remove);
        filmButton = new ArrayList<>();
        container.revalidate();
        container.repaint();
    }

    private void createDateButtons() {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(
                0, 0, // grid x, y
                1, 1, // grid width x, y
                0.3, 0.5, // weight , x, y
                GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START, // anchor
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH, // fill
                new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5),
                0, -100 // ipad x, y
        );

        for(Screening screening : screeningList) {
            JButton button = createScreeningButton(screening);
            button.setToolTipText(getFilmInfo(screening));


            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                        setSelectedButton(button);
                        FilmsEvent event = new FilmsEvent(e, screening);
                        fireFilmEvent(event);
                    }
            );

            container.add(button, gbc);
            filmButton.add(button);

            if(gbc.gridx == 1) {
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy++;
            } else {
                gbc.gridx++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void setSelectedButton(JButton button) {
        filmButton.stream().forEach(b -> b.setEnabled(true));
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private JButton createScreeningButton(Screening screening) {
        int startHours = screening.getStartTime().getHour();
        int startMinutes = screening.getStartTime().getMinute();
        String fullTitle = "<html>" +
                screening.film.getTitle() +
                "<br /> sakums: " +
                String.format("%02d:%02d", startHours, startMinutes) +
                "<br /> garums: " +
                screening.film.getDurationTime() +
                "<br /> brivas vietas- " +
                screening.auditorium.getEmptySeats() +
                "<br /> biletes cena- " +
                String.format("%.2f", screening.getTicketPrice()) +
                "</html>";
        JButton button = new JButton( fullTitle, screening.film.getIcon());
        button.setDisabledIcon(screening.film.getIcon());
        return button;
    }

    private void fireFilmEvent(FilmsEvent event) {
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();

        for(int index = 0; index < listeners.length; index += 2) {
            if (listeners[index] == FilmsListener.class) {
                ((FilmsListener) listeners[index + 1]).moviesEventOccurred(event);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getFilmInfo(Screening screening) {

        return  "<html>" +
                screening.film.getTitle() +
                ".<br /> zanrs: " +
                screening.film.getGenre() +
                "<br /> Apraksts: " +
                splitString(screening.film.getDescription()) +
                "<br /> garums: " +
                screening.film.getDurationTime() +
                ".<br /> valoda: " +
                screening.film.getLanguage() +
                ".<br /> subtitri: " +
                screening.film.getSubtitles() +
                ".<br /> ieteicamais vecums: " +
                screening.film.getRecommendedAge() +
                "</html>";
    }


    public static String splitString(String string) {
        String buf = "";
        String tempString = string;
        if (string != null) {
            while(tempString.length() > 60)
            {
                String block = tempString.substring(0, 60);
                int index = block.lastIndexOf(' ');
                if(index < 0) {
                    index = tempString.indexOf(' ');
                }
                if (index >= 0){
                    buf += (tempString.substring(0, index) + "<BR>");
                }
                tempString = tempString.substring(index+1);
            }
        }
        else {
            tempString = " ";
        }
        buf += tempString;
        return buf;
    }

}
```

2. What are other things you notice about the code that I should change/improve/work on?
3. What are industry standards for making things similar to this? Should I make interfaces where it assembles for example button title, button image? It seems like a lot of classes for such a little thing.

Comment: I prefer to make class members "final" by default. Meaning: Only when it is very clear that a member has to change over time; then I avoid using final. I think that using final (for member fields) has two big advantages: the compiler will tell you if you forget to initialize a field; and secondly, it can make multi-threading a lot easier. When dealing with "value" only classes (like String, Integer, ...) ... you don't have to worry about concurrent "write" scenarios of all such field are final.

Comment: I feel like there is a huge convention about encapsulating all class members. Should I crate `.getAuditorium ()` and `getFilm` methods? And I should what would be the purpose of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll leave it to others to for the GUI review, I only have a suggestion for your `Screening` class:

## Constructor arguments positioning

It is sometimes recommended to order constructor arguments by their requirements, e.g.

```
public Class(A argA) {
    this(argA, defaultArgB); 
}

public Class(A argA, B argB) {
    this(argA, argB, defaultArgsC);
}

public Class(A argA, B argB, C... argsC) {
    ...
}
```

The benefits of doing so are:

- It is easier to remember what arguments must be supplied, and what has default values.
- It is easier to 'swap' constructors, e.g. during testing, by simply adding or removing the last argument.
- If any arguments are expected to be in an array form, you can make use of the `varargs` feature (see final example above for `C... argsC`) to slightly simplify the declaration.
- It helps to prevent careless mistakes when you have the same or convertible argument types. E.g. if you happen to be taking a bunch of `String`s. Assume type `B` extends `A` and if the second example above was written as such:

  ```
  public Class(B argB, A argA) {
      this(argA, argB, defaultArgsC);
  }
  ```

  If you accidentally remove the second argument of such a constructor call: `new Class(objB, objA)` to just `new Class(objB)`, `objB` gets up-casted and is treated like any instance of `A` instead. This may make understanding the code at 3 am *harder*... of course, if there's no relationship between these two types, you'll get a straightforward compilation error immediately, which is still bad at 3 am...

## Other possible areas for improvements

- Your `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementations for `Screening` appears to be generated by your IDE of choice, but in any case Java 7 already has [`Objects.hash()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29) and [`Objects.deepEquals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), so you may want to consider using them instead.
- I don't have much experience with the new `Time` APIs of Java 8, but I have a feeling some of your calculations or formatting (see `getDurationTime() and setLenghtInHours()` in `Film`) can be easier done without having to perform the calculations yourself.
- `Auditorium.of()` seems to be unused, consider removing it?

  - Speaking of your `Auditorium` class, I find it unusual that its usage seem to necessitate the creation of new instances quite often, such as whenever you have a new `Screening` (without specifying the `auditorium` argument). Your may want to review your model too...

Comment: Thanks for advices and correcting me of me being sloppy. Also about those unused methods: **should I write unused methods** if I fill it is like plus and minus? For example I would most of the time write `get` and `set` or `add` and `remove` methods if I think there is no reason no to do it. Any other advice? What would you do differently except this?

Comment: If getters and setters are generated, then I think it's fine. The less code you write upfront, the less chances of bugs. :) Related note: [You Aren't Gonna Need It (YAGNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)